# Using su to copy/move a file

Tags: android, su

I'm pulling out my hair trying to get a copy or move of a file to work using su.

I've tried:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cat " + sourceLocation.getAbsolutePath() + " > " + targetLocation.getAbsolutePath());
```

and

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su cp " + sourceLocation.getAbsolutePath() + " " + targetLocation.getAbsolutePath());
```

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid and obvious, but I can't pin it down.

Also, is there any way to request SU one time for all my processes?  Each time I use it, it's triggering another dialogue.

Comment: I would recommend checking out [RootTools](https://code.google.com/p/roottools/w/list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root tools takes care of the trickiness.

```
 CommandCapture command = new CommandCapture(0, "cp -f " + sourceLocation + " " + targetLocation);
 RootTools.getShell(true).add(command);
```